# How to interpret categorical variable significant ANOVA interaction in R?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, interaction

[image]

I have this output from a R ANOVA analysis and the graph attached. I want to verify if the interpretation for the scenario is correct?

```
                      Estimate   Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)             1.7918     0.6236   2.873  0.00206 **
typeHigh               -1.5911     0.7687  -2.070  0.01847 * 
statusBlack            -1.2528     0.7843  -1.597  0.11018   
typeHigh:statusBlack    2.4384     1.0628   2.294  0.01177 *
```

1. Line 4 of result -- The difference between the status: Black and Gray is different for the type: Low vs High. Here, At low: black decreases w.r.t to gray and at high it increases w.r.t to gray
2. Line 1 of result -- How do I interpret the first line alone?
3. Finally, is it correct to say that as we go from low to high: Gray decreases significantly i.e. Gray in "Low" is different from Gray in "High". 
   Also, does black increase significantly i.e. Black in "Low" is different from Black in "High".

Comment: I ran a glm negative binomial function, so the values are from the estimate. Ignore those

Comment: negative binomial and ANOVA are totally different things. Then my first comment based on ANOVA is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A significant effect in an ANOVA analysis is interpreted as: At least one level of the categorical variable has a mean, which is significantly different from at least one other level. It tells you nothing regarding which group is different from any other group.

When a categorical by categorical interaction is added to the model the groups are broken down into their memberships on both variables. In your case, the 4 groups would be: low and black, low and grey, high and black, & high and grey.

The interaction coefficient simply tells you that one of those 4 groups means is statistically significantly different from at least one other.

To understand which group is different, many methods exist. p-value corrected pairwise tests can be used, dummy coded regression models, or simply graphical methods.

Comment: The model is not ANOVA, it is based on negative binomial, as OP said in the comment.

Comment: I see that, but also see that they say to ignore that output. I provide an answer to the question asked, and the 4 points put forth in the OP.